# Checking the equality of same numbers returns False

Tags: python, equality

As a beginner in Python, I couldn't understand why checking equality of two numbers returns always False regardless of their values. Should I use another operator to check whether two numbers are equal? I will appreciate any help.

```
for index in range(len(array)):
    for index2 in range(len(array)):
        if(index!=index2):
            print array[index2][2]==index,array[index2][2],index,"\n"
```

Array is list of tuples where third item of tuples contain numbers.

Output:

```
False 1 0 

False 1 0 

False 1 0 

False 6 0 

False 7 0 

False 1 0 

False 7 0 

False 8 0 

False 8 0 

False 0 1 

False 1 1 

False 1 1 

False 6 1 

False 7 1 

False 1 1 

False 7 1 

False 8 1
```

Comment: provide [mcve] please

Comment: What’s loading your array? Are you sure it has integer contents?

Comment: Try this: `print("1"==1, 1, "1")` it's probably your problem...

Comment: Yes that is the problem, thanks.

Comment: How can I use them as numbers then?

Comment: Well just convert your strings to int using `int` function...